# Get the ouput result for a python script in a Jenkinsfile pipeline groovy

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I'm trying to assign to variable the ouput of a python script.

here is my setp

```
stage('Deployment on FTP') {
    steps {
        script {
            def warName = sh(script: 'python ../scripts/myPythonScriptHere.py', returnStdout: true)
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Here is my configuration (on a linux server) :

```
ci/
    -- prod/
                -- Jenkinsfile.groovy
    -- scripts/
                -- myPythonScriptHere.py
```

Jenkins tells can't open file "..." [Errno 2] No such file or directory

How can I do this ?

Thank you

Comment: Paths in shell script are relative to WORKSPACE. So is your script supposed to be in `$WORKSPACE/../scripts/myPythonScriptHere.py` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stage('Deployment on FTP') {
        steps {
            script {
                env.WAR_NAME = sh(script: "python scripts-ci/scripts/build/front/scripts/lib/war_name.py ${customerProfileId} ${FORCE_CUSTOMER_NAME}", returnStdout: true).toString().trim()
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code of my current Jenkinsfile working (scripts-ci beeing the folder when I've clone my python scripts needed.

```
        stage("Git checkout") {
          steps {
            dir("scripts-ci") {
                git branch: "${GIT_BRANCH_CI}",
                credentialsId: "${GIT_CREDENTIALS_ID}",
                url: "${GIT_URL_CI}"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration you have done here is itself incorrect. Inside of sh(script: ....) the function expects a shell script. Here pythons execution won't work. To get the output of the python, you will have to write a shell script that does this job for you. That means, you will have to write a shell script inside sh(script:...) that will execute your python script and capture it's output inside a variable and return it. E.g:

````
                  steps {
                    script {
                       def warName = sh(script: '#!bin/bash
                       var output = python ../scripts/myPythonScriptHere.py
                       return output', returnStdout: true)
        }
    }
}```
````